# SSL port is closed, when application redirect?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, redirect

So, I have Spring Boot application, that have SSL certificate, when I run my app from localhost, everything work fine, I write my domain example.com and next I have redirect to https://example.com

But when I run application from server, and visit my website from another computer, I have problem, my port 433 where happened redirect is closed. Port `80` is open for server IP. So, site doesn't open

**My Configiration**

```java
    @Configuration
    public class TomcatConfigure {
        
        
        @Bean
        public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
            TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {@Override
                protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                    SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                    securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                    SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                    collection.addPattern("/*");
                    securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                    context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
                }
            };
            tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(redirectConnector());
            return tomcat;
        }
    
        private Connector redirectConnector() {
            Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL); //("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
            connector.setScheme("http");
            connector.setPort(80);
            connector.setSecure(false);
            connector.setRedirectPort(443);
            return connector;
        }
```

```
    ###Properties
    server.port=433
    server.address=0.0.0.0
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/law?useSSl=false
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = 123456789Vv
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    spring.main.allow-circular-references=true
    
    ## SSL 
    server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl/vsprava.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password=123456789Vv
    server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,SSLv3,SSLv2,TLS
    server.ssl.key-alias=1
    server.http2.enabled=true
```

Port cheeker say that port `433` is closed.

Comment: There is a typo 443 vs 433

Comment: port 433 for ssl Sertificate

Comment: vsprava.com:433

Comment: Default SSL is 443 but you have redirect in code to 443 but 433 in properties...

Comment: what i can write?

Comment: `server.port=443`